# How to sketch trigonometric functions?

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

I was given this as an assignment in Calculus for Life Sciences and I really would like to figure it out:

**sketch:**

> y=sinx, y=cosx, y=tanx over
>
> -2x≤x≤2x

Comment: do you mean $-2\leq x \leq 2$? or $-2\pi \leq x \leq 2\pi$?

Comment: Is $-2x\leq x \leq 2x$ right?

Comment: yes it is, that's what was given

Comment: should be $$ -2 \pi \leq x \leq 2 \pi  $$

Comment: Take a look at http://www.touchmathematics.org/topics/trigonometry to get a visual understanding of how it relates to the unit circle. You can check and uncheck the functions one by one to clean it up a little.

Comment: have you looked at the graphs of these functions in your textbook? If so, what exactly do you want us to do for you?

Comment: @TylerHilton I will try

Comment: @BernardMassé I already checked the textbook for a guide but to no avail. There isn't anything to help with that question

Comment: Take out some graph paper, punch some numbers into a calculator, and plot the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with the graphs of $\sin x$ and $\cos x,$ and you know that $\tan x=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x},$ then you will notice that $\tan x$ has vertical asymptotes where $\cos{x}$ has $x-$intercepts and $x-$ intercepts where $\sin{x}$ has $x-$intercepts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also confused about the interval you have been given. But if you want to know how to sketch trigonometric functions, this page might be of some help:
http://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Precalculus/Section_5.3-Trigonometric%20Graphs/Trigonometric%20Graphs.pdf